# How to filter logcat to remove irrelevant statements

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I'm new to Android Studio, using latest version, and trying to code a basic calculator app.

For some reason, my logcat is full of
`2021-01-11 14:38:35.288 6938-6938/? W/cmd: Can't find service car_service`

This is really annoying for debugging.

How can I get rid of it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll change my comment to an answer, seeing as though it actually helped:

click on logcat at the bottom of android studio, then (i'm assuming) yours will show `no filters`, change that dropdown to `show only selected application`. Not really much I can explain here, except for the fact that if you don't have it setup like this, logcat will print out things which are irrelevant to your app in addition to the logs from your own application

Comment: (Moved comment here) You're 100% right. Changing to show only selected application worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, to all future readers... Android Logcat is quite verbose, especially on Emulators (where a lot of things throw errors/warnings) but not limited to; Samsung devices spit more log than useful information (And they are not alone), so a way to keep it under *some* control, is to (ab)use the Regex feature of the logcat filter in Android Studio.

E.g.:

Create a new LogCat Filter and filter by Tag, Message, or Package (or all 3 like I do):

This is an example I use in "Message":

```
^((?!EGL_emulation|eglCodecCommon|OpenGLRenderer|MicroDetectionWorker|MicroDetector|KeyguardClockSwitch|adbd|OIMC|base.apk|wakelock|com.google.android.apps.youtube.music).)*$
```

You can edit/add more to these and/or repeat it for LogTag, Message, or Package Name.

It's mostly trial and error. (some devices spit different spam via logcat).

My Log Tag filter for this "very filtered app" output is:

```
^((?!vendor.qti.bluetooth|AppDynamics|KeyguardUpdateMonitor|BatteryExternalStatsWorker|BatteryStatsService|tftp_server|Clock|libc|OnePlusSmartBoostManager|OnePlus|ANDR-RAMBOOST_SERVER|BoundBrokerSvc|DateView|BatteryStatsHelper|BoundBrokerSvc|RenderThread|FacsCacheGmsModule|DownloadProgressMonitor|MendelPackageState|GoogleTagManager|SELinux|Volley|ConfigFileUtils|NetRec|YouTubeMusic|GEL_DELAYED_EVENT_DEBUG|gms|AsyncOperation|angh|ContentCacheSuperpacksManager|SuperpacksManager|AwarenessClientProvider|WakeLock|GLSUser|perfetto|cmd|chatty|Binder|Fitness|Icing|GnssHAL_GnssInterface).)*$
```

and for Package Name:

```
^((?!EGL_emulation|eglCodecCommon|OpenGLRenderer|MicroDetectionWorker|MicroDetector|KeyguardClockSwitch|adbd|OIMC|base.apk|wakelock|com.google.android.apps.youtube.music).)*$
```

Of course *your mileage will vary* in what you need, and sometimes I edit these and add/remove some parts as I see fit.

This is how it looks:

[image: Image of Android Studio Dialog creating a New Logcat Filter]

[image: LogCat bar showing the Regex Checkbox checked and selected Filter created above]